# Restricted picklist issue even providing correct value

Tags: picklist

In a test class, I'm passing a value of a restricted picklist. Below is the value, and the screenshot of the restricted picklist LOVs:-

```
SVMXC__Quote_Line__c testQuoteLine = new SVMXC__Quote_Line__c();
testQuoteLine.ESMX_Maintenance_Window__c='SWE Reg – Regular Labour, Semi-Weekend (e.g. Saturday)';
```

[image]

Even though, as it can be seen, we are passing the correct value, we are getting the below error while running the test class:-

> System.DmlException: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id a34g0000000v3ceAAA; first error: INVALID_OR_NULL_FOR_RESTRICTED_PICKLIST, Maintenance Window: bad value for restricted picklist field: SWE Reg – Regular Labour, Semi-Weekend (e.g. Saturday): [ESMX_Maintenance_Window__c]

N.B.: No record type or Field dependency issue faced here.

Answer (score 5):

probably the value you want to enter isnt exposed to the record type.

1. go to the object`s record type
2. select the relevant one
3. select the relevant "picklists Available for Editing" for edit
4. add the values

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue and it turned out that I didn't have the correct field dependency set.  If you're also using Field Dependencies, check to ensure the value in question is enabled for the correct controlling field values.

Answer (score 0):

Since, picklist values have been stored as API Name (in the database), so you need to assign the API Name of the picklist item.

```
SVMXC__Quote_Line__c testQuoteLine = new SVMXC__Quote_Line__c();
testQuoteLine.ESMX_Maintenance_Window__c='SWE Reg';
```

In the UI, it will be displayed as value [`SWE Reg – Regular Labour, Semi-Weekend (e.g. Saturday)`]

Comment: Hi Santanu, Thank you for the response.
However, even providing the API name, I'm encountering the same issue.

Comment: Is that script is getting run by a specific user? Do you have any recordtype?

Comment: As mentioned, there is no record type restriction. Also the script is not being run by any user. The FLS is set to the user which I'm logged in.

Comment: check that any space is there in the API Name, Also, suggest you to create a record from UI and check how it is storing as SVMXC__Quote_Line__c's record and replicate same data in test class

Comment: Have you specified default value on picklist field? Please check this link https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000250168&language=en_US&type=1.

Comment: @SantanuBoral hy, i have similar issue like this, and there is space in API Name (ex: Loss Deal). in this case what should i do to insert data using dataloader, cause i always get error restricted picklist